# random 2-dimensional vectors, $X_n$ is uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf, uniform-distribution

Let $(X_1 ,X_2, \ldots)$ be an independent sequence of random 2-dimensional vectors, where for each $n$, $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on the squares with vertices  $[\pm n,\pm n]$.

How can I calculate the probability $$ P(\{w: |X_n(w)| \rightarrow \infty \ \ as \ n \rightarrow \infty\}).$$

My attempt:

Let $A_n=\{ w \in \Omega | |X_k| \geq k\}$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, then $$ P(A_n)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             0 &   if  & k \geq \sqrt{2}n \\
             \\ 1-\frac{k^2 \pi}{n^2} &  if & k \leq n \\
             \\ c(k) &  if  & n < k < \sqrt{2}n 
             \end{array}
   \right. $$

for $c(k)$ a certain value depending of $k$.

I that correct? Or How can I compute the probability on this $A_n=\{|X_n(w)| < n^\alpha\}$ ?

Could someone help pls? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: what is $c(k)$?

Comment: also ... to understand, $X_1$ is a random vector in the square defined by (-1,-1) left hand lower corner and (1,1) upper right hand corner

Comment: is a certain value depending of k, that $P(A_n)$ was an advice for my teacher but I don't know how he calculated that probability

Comment: @phdmba7of12 Yes, $X_1$ is that you said

Comment: but How can I calculate $A_n=\{|X_n(w)| < n^\alpha\}$ for a well chosen $\alpha$? I don't understand that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the same approach I showed you in your previous question ?

Since all norms on $\mathbb R^2$ are equivalent, let $\|\cdot\|$ denote the maximum norm (its unit ball is a square, how convenient...).

Note that $\displaystyle P(\|X_n\|\to \infty)= P\left(\bigcap_N\bigcup_n \bigcap_{k\geq n}(\|X_k\| \geq N)\right)$.

Since the sequence of sets (indexed by $N$) $\bigcup_n \bigcap_{k\geq n}(\|X_k\| \geq N)$ is decreasing, $$P\left(\bigcap_N\bigcup_n \bigcap_{k\geq n}(\|X_k\| \geq N)\right)=\lim_N P\left(\bigcup_n \bigcap_{k\geq n}(\|X_k\| \geq N)\right)$$

so it suffices to compute $P\left(\bigcup_n \bigcap_{k\geq n}(\|X_k\| \geq N)\right)$ for each $N$.

But $P\left(\bigcup_n \bigcap_{k\geq n}(\|X_k\| \geq N)\right)$ is nothing other than $$P(\liminf_n \|X_n\|\geq N) = 1-P(\limsup_n \|X_n\|<N)$$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\|X_n\|< N)=\sum_{n=1}^N 1 + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{N^2}{n^2}< \infty$, Borel-Cantelli lemma yields $P(\limsup_n \|X_n\|<N) = 0$, hence $P(\liminf_n \|X_n\|\geq N)=1$ for all $N$.

Therefore, $P(\|X_n\|\to \infty)=1$.

Comment: I tried to compute in other way it’s still complicate this for me, for example how can I calculate the LMI sup of a set? I know tha I have to see unions and intersection but it’s a little bit confusing for me

Comment: I was analyzing your answer and even in the previus question that I made, why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\|X_n\|< N)=\sum_{n=1}^N 1 + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{N^2}{n^2}$ ? where do you get $\sum_{n=1}^N 1 $ ?

Comment: when $n\leq N$, $X_n$ lies almost surely in a square of side $n$ which is a subset of the square of side $N$. Hence $P(\|X_n\|< N)=1$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{N^2}{n^2}$ and this is because we have that the r.v.´s are uniformly distributed ?

Comment: @Knight yes, this is the reason

Answer (score 0):

If $X_n\not\to\infty$, then some subsequence must remain bounded, which for large $n$ is unlikely. To make this idea a little more formal, take a sequence $(a_n)$ that goes to infinity slowly ($a_n=\log n$ will do) and show that $P(|X_n|\le a_n) $ is summable. You can then apply Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: what is that $P(|X_n| \leq a_n )$ is summable?

Comment: It means $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n|\le a_n)<\infty$. It is not hard to show this with $a_n=\log n$, since if $X_n=(U_n,V_n)$, $U_n$ and $V_n$ are independent uniform on $[-n,n]$ so $P(|X_n|\le \log n)\le P(|U_n|\le \log n,|V_n|\le \log n)$, and then you can use independence.